# sketch graph of function

Tags: graphing-functions

Sketch a possible graph of a function that satisfies the given conditions. 
  (0)=−2,(2)=4
′(2)=0,′(1) is not defined
  ′()<0 on (−∞,1) and (2,∞)
 ′′()>0 on (−∞,1)
 ′′()<0 on (1,∞)

Answer (score 0):

Lets try and write examine these special conditions. Firstly

Look at gradients. It is negative everywhere except on[1,2] and 0 at 2.

Then we see that if it isnt a line what kind of convex it will be. We use the 2nd derivative to find this. Finally we move the graphs till they satisfy the conditions, also, but having a discontinuity at 1, prevents *f '(x)*   being defined there

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzt7A.png) to see a graph which satisfies the conditions you stated. I leave it to you to check them.